# Switch role wise screen in asp net zero, if one user has multiple roles

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

I have checked asp net-zero document for role-wise change display screen based on roles permissions but in asp net-zero, A user can have zero or more roles. If a user has more than one role, the user inherits a union of permissions of all these roles.
but I want a dropdown to select the role and based on selected roles permitted screens for users.

Comment: Create one role per permission?

Comment: @aaron No, 1 user with multiple roles and then we can switch roles and based on role selected and permitted screens of role only display screens

Comment: Add a new entity `SelectableRole` and handle accordingly.